# Call a specific macro for one cell, based on the value of another cell

Tags: vba

I have a macro `GETGUID()`. Would want to call the macro on Column 'B' whenever the corresponding column 'A' has a value in it. If Column A is empty, then GETGUID macro should not be called for the corresponding column B.

I tried the following code, but it is not working. For a test, I am using range A1:A20 but it can be any range. GETGUID() macro works fine if I type manually in column B but I want this to work whenever corresponding cell in column A has some value.

My knowledge in using Macros is not so good. Here is the code I am trying:

```
Public Function GetGUID() As String
    GetGUID = Mid$(CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib").GUID, 2, 36)
End Function

Dim cell_to_test As Range, cells_changed As Range

Set cells_changed = Target("A1:A20")
Set cell_to_test = Range("B1:B20")

If Not Intersect(cells_changed, cell_to_test) Is Nothing Then
    Range("B1:B12") = GetGUID()
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a simple Macro which loops through each cell declared by `Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A20")`. If a value is present (not `vbNullString`) then the column to the right is populated with a GUID.

```
 Private RANGE_CELL As Range

 Public Function GetGUID() As String
        GetGUID = Mid$(CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib").GUID, 2, 36)
    End Function

Public Sub Populate_B()
    For Each RANGE_CELL In Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A20")
        If RANGE_CELL <> vbNullString Then
            RANGE_CELL.Offset(, 1).Value = GetGUID
        Else
            '// Do nothing.
        End If
    Next RANGE_CELL
End Sub
```

Let me know if you need anything, happy to help.

Comment: If you're looking to add the GUID when column A is populated you can add the following Macro to the worksheet page:

`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        If Target.Value <> vbNullString Then Target.Offset(, 1).Value = GetGUID
    End If
End Sub`

Comment: Thanks @Nulled. I tried this code as well as the one provided by you above but it does not work. It must be something small which I am not able to figure out due to my very limited knowledgePrivate RANGE_CELL As Range

 Public Function GetGUID() As String
        GetGUID = Mid$(CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib").GUID, 2, 36)
    End Function

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 1 Then
If Target.Value <> vbNullString Then Target.Offset(, 1).Value = GetGUID
End If

End Sub

Comment: You'll need to open the VBA Editor, double click the worksheet you need the GUID to populate on and paste in the code from my comment. Once the code is within the worksheet you can close the VBA Editor, navigate to the sheet in Excel and add a value to column A. The macro should then add a GUID to the cell in column B. If you've done this and it isn't working then could you send me the debug message you receive?

Comment: Thank you so much. I was writing the code in the module I create for the sheet. Now, I wrote the code after double clicking it and it worked. I appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem. Happy holidays. :)